# How do I use CGI in a Heroku application written with Ruby and Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, heroku, cgi, sinatra

I am trying to move information from a text form to a new web page using CGI. To do this, I set `action` to `action="new.html"` in the form. Then, in the relevant part of my `.rb` file, I have:

```
get "/new.html" do
  @graph  = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:access_token])
  @app  =  @graph.get_object(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"])

  if session[:access_token]
    @query=CGI.new()         # Line of interest
    @input=@query["tool_1"]  # Line of interest
  end

  erb :my_tools_F
end

post "/new.html" do
  redirect "/new.html"
end
```

The new web page loads, but `@input` is blank when I call it in the `.erb` file.  Prior to this part of the script, I did require CGI. My web host is Heroku, and both of the `.erb` files are in a directory called `views`. The application is built to be launched on Facebook.

The example code is [here](https://github.com/runninggraeb/Toolshed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to get the parameters for the form. I had another answer here but that wasn't working for you. You can easily do this without cgi and you should consider using the built in methods to do so. However, before you can do that I noticed some errors in your github post.

Your folder `Views` should read `views`. Small but it matters. I couldn't get the pages rendering correctly.

On your `new.erb` and `index.erb` on line 33 it reads:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add"">
```

There is an extra `"` at the end. Just remove it to look like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add">
```

Lastly, to do what you need to do:

```
get "/new.html" do
  erb :new
end

post "/new.html" do
  @input = params[:tool_1]
  erb :new
end
```

instead of what you did. Do a find on http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro for params.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but "@input" was still empty when I used this.

Comment: I would love to help you debug this. Can you write a degenerate version of your code that replicates the error without the facebook authentication? Post it on gist, github or whatever.

Comment: I will, but the new version won't be up until late tomorrow, if I don't run into any hurdles.

Comment: The partial code for this application can now be found at "https://github.com/runninggraeb/Toolshed", and you can see the app at "https://immense-garden-8474.herokuapp.com/".

Comment: For anybody else who's having trouble with this, there's a gread Sinatra tutorial at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/singing-with-sinatra/